# AdBannerView not serving ads on iOS7

Tags: ios7, iad

Just want to make sure if this is just me. My app when running on the iOS6 simulator or a iOS6 device is serving iAds just fine. The same app running on the iOS7 Simulator or devices never serves ads.

> ** Failed to receive ad - The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error

Comment: I'm having the same problem, ios 6 works perfectly but with ios7 simlador gives me the error in the method bannerView: didFailToReceiveAdWithError:, but my error is (Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=3 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Ad inventory unavailable" UserInfo=0x16d94a80 {ADInternalErrorCode=3, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Ad inventory unavailable}) hope you comfort.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel better, I'm getting this too.  Works in iOS 6 simulator, but I get the error in the iOS 7 simulator and my iOS 7 device.  I'm hoping this is just a problem with debug mode and not a problem when the app is deployed.

Comment: It's not really an answer - say this as a comment instead. It would be useful to say why it's happening, what can be done...

Answer (score 0):

As of today Apple seems to have fixed it.